# Date.prototype.getHours() not work

Tags: javascript

chrome v61.0.3163.100

```
var date = new Date("2017-11-15T04:00:00Z");
console.log(date) //Wed Nov 15 2017 04:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
console.log(date.getHours() === date.getUTCHours()) //true
```

safari v11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7)

```
var date = new Date("2017-11-15T04:00:00Z");
console.log(date) //Wed Nov 15 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
console.log(date.getHours() === date.getUTCHours()) //false
```

Why the same piece of code in different browsers operating results are different, sometimes in the same browser, there are differences

---------update-----------

When I reply to you, Chrome has output "Wed Nov 15 2017 12:00:00 GMT + 0800 (CST)", this is a sad question. In the meantime, I only had lunch and did not set the timeZone.

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone 

after => "America/Chicago"

befor => "China/Shanghai"(this is true)
```

> [mdn document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours): An integer number, between 0 and 23, representing the hour for the given date according to local time.

Comment: The behavior described in the first example doesn't make any sense to me unless you're running the code on a machine that has its timezone set to UTC (are you doing that?). `Date` objects don't "have" a time zone, so the fact that it's displaying as `Wed Nov 15 2017 04:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)` when you log it suggests that there's something going on that you haven't told us. It produces `false` in Chrome 62 on my machine and displays in my local timezone.

Comment: @JLRishe When I reply to you, Chrome has output "Wed Nov 15 2017 12:00:00 GMT + 0800 (CST)", this is a sad question.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the second example, the time is stored with an offset (+0800), while in the first, it is not (+0000). `getHours()` returns the *local* hour, while `getUTCHours()` is the UTC hour.

The difference appears to be in the browser storage of the timezone, which both have their advantages. Obviously which one you use depends on the circumstance, but the difference lies in the offset (shown in the string representation).

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `Date` objects don't have their own timezone and I'm unable to reproduce OP's described behavior in Chrome. I think there's something else going on here.

Comment: In both cases the date is stored as a UTC time value, the hours are always calculated depending on the method used (local for *getHours* and UTC for *getUTCHours*). The browser doesn't store the timezone, it gets it from the host system. The only way to get the result in the OP is to change the system timezone between running the examples, or run it on different hosts with different timezone settings (one set to GMT and the other set to CST).

Comment: @RobG How else would you explain the difference? The browsers clearly differ somehow.

Comment: @RobG When I reply to you, Chrome has output "Wed Nov 15 2017 12:00:00 GMT + 0800 (CST)", this is a sad question. In the meantime, I only had lunch and did not set the timeZone. 

Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone 

after => "America/Chicago"

befor => "China/Shanghai"

Comment: @jhpratt—apparently not any more. ;-)